# How do I create a data validation to ensure the sum of column does not exceed a specific amount on Google Sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am trying to create a data validation for the sum of columns on Google Sheets. The sum of percentages within the selected cell range in a particular column should not exceed 100% otherwise an error message etc that informs the user of the error should pop up. Lets assume I have percentages breakup data in the cell range C1:C20. I want to ensure that the collective sum of percentages in C1:C20 does not exceed 100%.

[link to a sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mv0KCBB_kwm2GgqZydJPMprt5srWje3ekJ125uzZDXo/edit#gid=0) whose data you can use for trying to help me out

Answer (score 1):

Validation rule of `C1:C20` - formula:

```
=SUM(C$1:C$20)<=1
```